# Angular material milliseconds time input on ios

Tags: html, angular, input, angular-material

I have a site in Angular, in which I have an input of type time, in which I also need to enter milliseconds (you have to enter a time per lap), my code is this:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
                  <mat-label>Lap time</mat-label>
                  <input matInput required name="lapTime" [(ngModel)]="lap_time" type="time" step="0.001"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

From desktop and mobile Android works properly:

[image]

While from iphone it only allows me to enter hours and minutes:

[image]

How can I make it so that seconds and milliseconds are also entered from iphone?

Comment: looks like safari doesn't support it: https://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: What can I use instead?

Comment: maybe an other input number, which will set seconds ? Have to do it manually if the browser does not support the native feature...